# decreaseIndentPattern has no effect

Tags: visual-studio-code, textmate, vscode-extensions, textmatebundles

I am trying to create a TextMate bundle for a new language but am having issues with the `decreaseIndentPattern`. It seems to have no effect whatsoever, even with a trivial example:

```
increaseIndentPattern = 'start';
decreaseIndentPattern = 'end';
```

I have set the scope correctly and the other settings in the same file do work (including the `increaseIndentPattern`). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that to enable indentation correction on text based files (my scope starts with `text`), the following is also required:

```
disableIndentCorrections = :false;
```